# MailApp.sendEmail returns strange error when assigning array variable as recipient

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets

I am simply trying to use script in my Google Sheet to send some emails but I am getting an odd error code.

Does the failure have something to do with the brackets around the stored array variable?

What am I missing?

This all works if I manually enter an email address into the script. And it works if I use a simple variable assignment instead of an array.

But I have seen many examples where an array variable is used in the "recipient" or "to" field of the sendEmail syntax.

```
 //Code A - this works
 for(var x=0; x <= emails.length; x++){
   if(checkedCells[x] = "True" && emails[x] != ""){ 

   console.log(emails[x]);
   var testEmail = "me@me.com";

      MailApp.sendEmail({
         to: testEmail,
         replyTo: replyEmail,
         subject: subjectLine,
         Body: messageBody,

      });

   }
 }


 //Code B - this gives an error
 for(var x=0; x <= emails.length; x++){
   if(checkedCells[x] = "True" && emails[x] != ""){ 

   console.log(emails[x]);

      MailApp.sendEmail({
         to: emails[x],
         replyTo: replyEmail,
         subject: subjectLine,
         Body: messageBody,

      });

   }
 }
```

Code A works fine.

Code B does not send the email and gives a different error each time, always beginning with "ERROR
Invalid email: [L" and ending with random characters like ";@388e5b32 at sendScreener(Code:690)"

I notice in the Stackdriver log that testEmail results in
me@me.com

While emails[x] results in 
[me@me.com]

...because it is an array variable. Does this matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved... just needed ".toString()"  after the array...

```
to: emails[x].toString()
```